# Error when performing a puppet agent run

Tags: puppet

I have puppetmaster and agents versions 3.8.7 installed.

When I do a Puppet run, I get the following error:

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on
>   SERVER: Syntax error at 'Enum'; expected ')' at
>   /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/concat/manifests/init.pp:46
>   on node wiki

Why is this happening?

Comment: Please convert these images into text.

Comment: The screenshots are not needed, the error is related to the concat module. Also, the screenshots are of code, so would be better replaced by code if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're running Puppet 3, whereas you have installed a recent version of the Puppet Concat module, which only supports Puppet 4 and 5.

If upgrading to Puppet 4 or 5 is not an option for you, you would need to install an older version of the Concat module that supports Puppet 3.

(Note that it's likely that you'll have the same problem with other modules too, as increasingly, Puppet 3 is no longer supported in Puppet Forge modules.)